# Induced subgraph problem

Tags: graph-theory

I have encountered a problem with this exercise: 
Given a simple graph $G$ with $n$ vertices such that every $k$ induced subgraph has the same number of edges, prove that $G$ is complete (clique) or the set of $n$ disjoint points.

Answer (score 0):

The following proof assumes that the condition

> every  induced subgraph has the same number of edges

stands for

> for any subsets $X$ and $Y$ of $V(G)$, the subgraphs of $G$ induced by $X$ and $Y$ have the same number of edges.

Assume for contradiction that neither $G$ nor $\overline{G}$ is complete. There are two pairs of vertices $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ such that
$a$ and $b$ are adjacent in $G$ and $c$ and $d$ are not adjacent in $G$, violating the condition with $X=\{a,b\}$ and $Y=\{c,d\}$ (i.e., $k=2$).